# SQL Server SELECT Query using "CASE... END" to select column but getting Column not found error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have onse SELECT statement to get distinct row and in which I have used "CASE" to get return column data from different table. But, some how in result it's not giving particualar column. Please see below sample query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.Col1,
    T2.Col2,
    CASE WHEN <My Condition > THEN T1.IncomeColumn
    ELSE
     T2.IncomeColumn
    END AS FinalIncome
FROM Table1 as t1  inner join Table2 as T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Here, as per above example If I am trying to user results of the query it's throwing "FinalIncome" Column not found error.

I have very lrge and time consuming to get result of this query so, it's difficult to get quick root cause.

please let me know if anyone have idea that what are the possibilties for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you actually show us your condition?

Comment: Either this query is part of a larger one that you're not showing us, or the condition you're not showing us is what's causing the problem. The query as written (with the `WHEN` added in) works just fine with a test condition.

Comment: Is there by any chance an ORDER BY clause that you are not showing us?  If so do you order by FinalIncome?  If so you need to order by the case expression and not the alias

Comment: You'll get an error like this if you try to *reference* `FinalIncome` within a calculation for another column within the *same* `SELECT` clause - you've not shown such a situation, but as the others are saying, the query you've shown us shouldn't cause the error you're describing at all.

Comment: "I have very lrge and time consuming to get result of this query so, it's difficult to get quick root cause." You should be testing your queries on farily limited amount of data or simulate your test on some temp tables to get faster results. You could also `PREPARE` your statement if some variables are changed during tests. Also, please give us the full query and your error log, since this isn't helpful - I think you are trying to do something with the query that you aren't really showing us.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `WHEN` in your `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.Col1,
    T2.col2,
    CASE 
        WHEN <My Condition> THEN T1.IncomeColumn
        ELSE T2.IncomeColumn
    END AS FinalIncome
FROM Table1 as t1 inner join Table2 as T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Can you post the `<My Condition>` as well?

Comment: Where am I missing "WHEN"

Comment: Ok, I see , that was my typo here in que. Sorry, for the same. But, in my actual query that was not an issue. but, some logical condition i m not able to track.

Answer (score 0):

As Francois correctly points out, you're missing a `when` in your `case`. I will add to his answer an alternate form of `case`:

```
select distinct
       t1.col1,
       t2.col2,
       case <some expression> when <value> then t1.incomecolumn
       else t2.incomecolumn end as finalincome
  from table1 as t1
       inner join
       table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

The above is more similar to a `switch` statement in application, where you create a case for each possible value of an expression that you're interested in.

```
select distinct
       t1.col1,
       t2.col2,
       case when <my condition> then t1.incomecolumn
       else t2.incomecolumn end as finalincome
  from table1 as t1
       inner join
       table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

This form is the more verbose of the two, and overkill for some common sitations where you might create a different condition for each value of a pre-defined code (*e.g., a `status` field that only has a few possible values, such as "OPEN", "CLOSED", "PENDING", etc.*).

The advantage this version has is it is the only way of handling `null` values:

```
case when <some column> is null then 'null brah' else <some column> end
```

Attempting to do this with the first syntax will lead to an error:

```
case <some column> when null then 'null brah' else <some column> end
```

Comment: Yes, as I added in my comments to reply fancois, It was typo here in my que and in my actuall query there is no CASE syntax error. it was correctly mentioned

select distinct
       t1.col1,
       t2.col2,
       case when <my condition> then t1.incomecolumn
       else t2.incomecolumn end as finalincome
  from table1 as t1
       inner join
       table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id;